# Map tiles not loading on desktop version, although the markers are correctly placed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

desktop ad mobile version of project [HERE](http://doyour.travel/?nolanding=1)

when loading through mobile device - map loads normally, but when throught PC - onle markers placed on the map, but tiles are not loaded - the grey area apperas instead of map...

P.S. Got some problem with "+" and "-" appearance on Zoom Control - if you know something about this issue - will be appreciate for pointing on the bug.
P.P.S. It all worked fine before today Google`s update of map style. No changes were applied to js since 10-09-2015, yesterday everything worked normally

Comment: How many people will ask the same question today? It was working yesterday, it doesn't work today...

Comment: Happens every time a new release of the API is pushed...

Comment: may be you have some ideas how to fix it, instead of yelling?

Comment: It works just fine for me on both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in not pointing the version of api in including script tag -
I included js with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=geometry&sensor=false>
```

when I changed to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21&key=API_KEY&libraries=geometry&sensor=false">
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.20&key=API_KEY&libraries=geometry&sensor=false">
```

it worked fine - 
when I use exp:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22&key=API_KEY&libraries=geometry&sensor=false">` 
- issue comes back

Now changed to 3.21